# Shadowsock ss-local doesn't change IP address

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I'm using ss-local to connect to a shadowsocks server. I can connect to this server easily with android shadowsocks app and it works perfectly but on my linux client my ip doesn't change after connection.

this is my config.json file:

```json
{
    "server":"<my server ip>",
    "server_port":"<port>",
    "mode":"tcp_and_udp",
    "local_port":1080,
    "password":"<password>",
    "timeout":1000,
    "method":"chacha20-ietf-poly1305",
    "workers":4,
    "fast_open":true,
    "reuse_port":true,
    "route":"all",
    "remote_dns":"dns.google",
    "local_address":"0.0.0.0",
    "local_port":1080
}
```

and this is the command i use:

```shell
ss-local -c ~/config.json
```

this is the output i get:

```
 2022-10-02 19:42:09 INFO: using tcp fast open
 2022-10-02 19:42:09 INFO: initializing ciphers... chacha20-ietf-poly1305
 2022-10-02 19:42:09 INFO: listening at 127.0.0.1:1080
 2022-10-02 19:42:09 INFO: tcp port reuse enabled
 2022-10-02 19:42:09 INFO: udprelay enabled
 2022-10-02 19:42:09 INFO: udp port reuse enabled
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```json
    "local_address":"0.0.0.0",
    "local_port":1080
```

ss-local, opens a local socks5 port and you have to use ss-local in that way (eg. install an proxy switcher addon on your browser and try to connect to the port defined above (here `1080`) and it works) [its not a VPN or something, technically speaking, it doesnt have any tun service)

security note: change `"local_address":"0.0.0.0"` to `"local_address":"127.0.0.1"`, by doing this, only applications on you computer can connect to this port.

`0.0.0.0` means, any devices which has an internet connection can connect to your ss-local (the most common adn easy to detect is when you use a public network eg. University network)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, I installed FoxyProxy on my firefox and tried to connect to 127.0.0.1:1080. I also changes my local_address to 127.0.0.1. But after connecting, I can't open any website. It just shows The connection has timed out.

Comment: reduce `wrokers` to 1 and change `remote_dns` to something else like `1.1.1.1`. meanwhile, try to connect using `telegram-desktop` for more reliable result or/and change proxy options inside Firefox settings to proper options (addons sometimes are not reliable)